# Unable to establish a psql session with remote heroku database

Tags: postgresql, heroku, heroku-postgres, heroku-cli

I have a remote heroku database ('hobby' tier) and want to establish a remote psql connection but when I type:

`heroku pg:psql`

I am receiving the following error:

```
psql: could not connect to server: Operation timed out
    Is the server running on host "ec2-54-163-230-199.compute-1.amazonaws.com" (54.163.230.199) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

I've edited postgresql.conf such that

`listen_addresses = '*'`

and added the line:

`host  all  all 0.0.0.0/0 md5`

to pg_hba.conf as I thought the issue may be my postgres configuration only accepting connections to localhost, but having restarted Postgres I am still getting the same error.

Anyone have any advice on what may be going wrong? If my firewall is blocking this would anyone have any advice on how to change that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: "I've edited postgresql.conf such that..."—where would you have done this? I'm fairly certain that Heroku doesn't provide a Postgres config file for you to edit. "and added... to pg_hba.conf"—it certainly doesn't provide a `pg_hba.conf` that you can modify.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I edited the postgresql.conf and pg_hba.conf in the data directory of my locally-installed Postgres (Postgres.app), as I thought it might be my local Postgres configuration that was preventing the connection from being established.

Comment: Those files have no effect whatsoever on `heroku pg:psql`. Are you behind a restrictive firewall? Does your application successfully connect to your database?

Comment: Thank you very much for this, I tried changing my internet connection to use my phone's hotspot and the connection was successful, therefore this must have been an issue with a restrictive firewall as you suggested - thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There must be network restrictions or firewall settings as it should work without making changes to conf file.